# homogeous of degre zero function

Tags: analysis

let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}-{0}$,  a positive homogeneous of degree zero function and $\lim_{x \to o} f(x) $ be exit, then f is a constant function.
why?

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$  is positive-homogeneous of degree zero if $f(t x)= f(x)$  for every t>0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not constant then $\exists x,y$ s.t $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Now $\lim_{t \to 0} f(tx)=f(x) \neq \lim_{t\to 0} f(ty)=f(y)$. Contradiction to the hypothesis as it was given that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Because homogeneous of degree zero functions are functions that are constant on 
every emanating ray from origin. Thus these functions uniquely determined when 
we know their values on $S^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists it means that $f$ has equal value on 
every emanating ray from origin and thus on $S^{n-1}$ and must be constant function.